# Force push to Gerrit even with no new changes

Tags: git, push, gerrit

I want to push a patchset to Gerrit which has already been pushed. Originally when the patches were sent up, the build system did not trigger. I need to trigger it again by resubmitting all patches.

Gerrit rejects this with

```
 ! [remote rejected] HEAD -> refs/for/branch (no new changes)
```

I know there are no new changes but I want to push anyway. How can I do this?

`--force` flag has no effect.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Execute "commit --amend, change the commit message and push again.

Comment: I have a lot of commits to push. Would rather not do this for each. Is there another way?

Comment: You want to push just to trigger the build system? Are you using Jenkins + Gerrit Trigger plugin?

Comment: Yes. I realized that I can just change commit message on the oldest commit and it will push all patches dependent on it as well. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @SazzadHissainKhan Just find the oldest non-merged commit and run an interactive rebase "rebase -i <oldest_git_sha>~1" and change "pick" to "edit" on the oldest commit and continue.  Then perform the command posted above by Marcelo and do "git rebase --continue" when done.